# Meaning of " He still wandered on, out of the little high valley, over its edge, and down the slopes beyond"

Tags: prepositions, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

What does this phrase:

> "He still wandered on, out of the little high valley, over its edge,
>   and down the slopes beyond"

mean exactly? The doubt is about the path defined. It's clear that he was walking without a defined destination, then:

- he passed the little valley? He avoided the little high valley?
- climbed to its edge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words. He wandered along the red line over the green ground, which I've shown in profile.

[image: Image showing route]

Comment: Wow! That's so good. What software did you use to make that "graph"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Um... Microsoft Paint.

Comment: Microsoft Paint has arrows?! (Rushes to open MP which she hasn't used since 2008)

Comment: Note the high valley is a valley in a mountain range, so still above sea level as shown by the slopes on the right

Comment: Also see Hanging Valleys: https://www.google.com/search?q=hanging+valley&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=zO&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Nu3nUbImhuryBK7UgegE&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1238&bih=732